# Facebook Tab to Salesforce & Back to Facebook Tab

Tags: facebook

Created a Static HTML Tab for a Lead Page in Facebook, asking for a form to be completed.

When the user clicks the "Submit" button, data is sent to my Salesforce Account, and the user then needs to go to a 2nd Facebook Tab which I've set up as a Thank-You Page.

Problem is that with iFrames, I can't get the Return URL to work as the user is already on the Facebook tab page when clicking "Submit."

Here's the code for the Submit Button... any advice would be appreciated:

(input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="https://facebook.com/member/thank-you/" /)

Comment: Where is the code? Use the code-button to insert.

Comment: (input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="https://facebook.com/member/thank-you/" /)